# scrapy shell did not recognize 'sel' object

Tags: scrapy

I'm a python newbie, and trying to using scrapy for project.
  Scrapy 0.19 is installed on my centos (linux 2.6.32) and I followed the instruction on scrapy document page,but found that,the scrapy shell could not find 'sel' object,here's my step:

```
[root@localhost rpm]# scrapy shell http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/_static/selectors-sample1.html
2014-03-02 06:33:23+0800 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.19.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2014-03-02 06:33:23+0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available: ssl, http11, libxml2
2014-03-02 06:33:23+0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Overridden settings: {'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0}
2014-03-02 06:33:23+0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-03-02 06:33:23+0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-03-02 06:33:23+0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-03-02 06:33:23+0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-03-02 06:33:23+0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-03-02 06:33:23+0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-03-02 06:33:23+0800 [default] INFO: Spider opened
2014-03-02 06:33:24+0800 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/_static/selectors-sample1.html> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   hxs        <HtmlXPathSelector xpath=None data=u'<html><head><base   href="http://example.c'>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/_static/selectors-sample1.html>
[s]   response   <200 http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/_static/selectors-sample1.html>
[s]   settings   <CrawlerSettings module=None>
[s]   spider     <BaseSpider 'default' at 0x3668ed0>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser

>>> sel.xpath('//title/text()')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sel' is not defined
>>>
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve? thx in advance

Comment: You must first **define** an object called `sel` with the attribute `xpath`. You can't ask Python to do something with something that doesn't exist and expect it to know what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sel` object was added in `0.20` version. And when you run the `shell` command it tells you which objects you can use, in your case, `hxs`, that has similar behaviour:

```
>>> hxs.select('//title/text()')
```

You should try to read the documentation first. In the `selectors` section is explained pretty clear how you can use them based in your current version.